# Destructive and interference waves with different waves

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, acoustics, interference

Yesterday I posted a question and, between the comments, I noted this:

> I wrote: ok, but for example can a blue laser and a violet laser interfere? I think that there isn't much different between their wavelenghts
>
> The answer: Yes, in theory, there can be an interference pattern between them, but this is highly theoretical. Keep in mind that the coherence length of a common laser pointer isn't usually much more than 10cm and the wavelengths in that vary by only about 10 to 20nm. If you mix blue and violet, you probably wont see any interference patterns more than a millimeter or so from where the waves mixed. As I said, it's possible but extremely difficult
>
> I wrote: *Blue laser and violet laser **encounter only in one point for cycle**, so we don't notice the interference. But if I take two blue laser, I'll see the interference because the waves concide. Is it right?*
>
> The answer: *If I interpreted you correctly, then yes, that is correct*

So I image that the bold text is something like this:
[image]

The waves, which have different wavelenghts because they are different, encounter only in two points in the image, so there is interference but it isn't very visible.

But now I'm thinking that also the destructive waves, which have the same wavelenght because they are the same waves,encounter in only two points:
[image]

And this waves interfere a lot between them, in fact they annul. Why don't the first two waves make a visible interference? Why don't they annul or interfere?
Does this mean that the bold text isn't right? Is it due to the different wavelenghts?

Comment: Short answer: add the y-values at every x-position to get the resulting wave. In the second picture, it always adds to zero; you get total destructive interference. In the first picture (let's make it easier and make amplitudes the same), you get constructive and destructive interference at different points. For short wavelengths, it'd be hard to tell that there is any interference at all without extremely precise (and possibly non-existent) equipment.

Answer (score 1):

A key feature of waves is that they move in both space and time.  The reason destructive interference is so interesting is that, at certain points in space, the equation for amplitude is 0, independent of time.  For those points of destructive interference, it doesn't matter what phase one beam is in, the other beam is always exactly 180 degrees out of phase with it, perfectly canceling it out.

If you like math, remember that the 1-d wave equation is $A(x,t)=A_{max}\sin(\frac{\lambda}{2\pi} x + \omega t)$  Destructive interference occurs when you have two waves with amplitudes $A_1$ and $A_2$ and different path lengths $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that the sum of their amplitudes is $$A_{total}(x_1,x_2,t)=A_1\sin(\frac{\lambda}{2\pi} x_1 + \omega t) + A_2\sin(\frac{\lambda}{2\pi} x_2 + \omega t)$$

Permit me some rearranging which makes the math more straightforward, I'll express the second wave as the sum of $A_1$ and $A_2-A_1$.  This is just a mathematical rearranging which makes the destructive interference more visible in the equations
$$A_{total}(x_1,x_2,t)=A_1[\sin(\frac{\lambda}{2\pi} x_1 + \omega t) + \sin(\frac{\lambda}{2\pi} x_2 + \omega t)] + (A_2-A_1)\sin(\frac{\lambda}{2\pi} x_2 + \omega t)$$

By notating it this way, we can see some common factors.  when $x1-x2$ is a multiple of $\frac{\lambda}{2}$ (i.e. there's a half-wavelength difference in their path lengths), then we see the two sine terms are always exactly $\frac{\pi}{2}$ out of phase or exactly in phase.  This is true regardless of what $t$ is.  This means that at these points, you have either maximally destructive or maximally constructive interference.

However, consider if the frequencies are different.  If the frequencies are different, then you no longer have that super-easy cancelation.  The sine terms will not always be perfectly out of phase with each other at all times.

There is a highly related concept called "beats," which occur when two signals which are close in frequency interfere in time.  They interfere in a way that's similar to the spatial interference you are looking at, but they do it in time.   It's most noticeable in sound waves.  If you have two frequencies which are close together, say 5000Hz and 5005Hz, you will hear them pulsing at the difference between those frequencies (in this case, 5 Hertz).

In your example, blue and violet do interfere this way, creating beats.  However, those beats are in the 10-20THz region.  This is way too fast to see pulsing directly, but far too slow for our human eyes to detect it as a photon...  That happens to be in the microwave region!

Comment: I didn't understand your explanation about the 1-d wave equation. Can you tell me it with other words?

Comment: If you have one frequency of coherent light, you get interference patterns because you get nulls where one light wave cancels the other out at all points in time.  If you have two frequencies, there is no point in space which always has 0 energy on it because the two wave are not in phase.

Comment: One thing that might help is to remember that what you've drawn is just the wave at one moment in time.  The wave moves as time progresses.

Comment: Well, so if the frequencies are very close, isn't there a noticeable interference patterns?

Comment: In theory, yes you could see beats appear if you got the frequencies close. Of course, given that the light frequencies you are looking at are roughly 600THz, and the human eye can just barely see flashing patterns of 24 Hertz (if you have very good eyes), if you had two lasers tuned within 0.000000000004% of each other's frequencies, you'd just barely make out the beats.  Any less perfectly tuned than that and the beats would be too fast to notice.

Comment: With an exotic camera like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1zmRulUaDk8) which can capture light on the femtosecond scale, you'd probably be able to see the nulls where the two light sources destructively interfere for a split second as the waves propagate.  I haven't run the math to see if the scales are such that it'd actually work, but I think that you'd be able to see the interference pattern evolving over time.  Of course, they pull a lot of tricks to make this work.  It is *not* your garden variety camera.

Comment: But if they have different(similar too, but different) frequencies that means that the waves (in the graphic) encounter theirselves two times for cycle , so I shouldn't see a noticeable interference

Comment: If they were very close, you would see a beating interference pattern, where the dark parts slowly move over time.  If the two beams were 1Hz apart, then the interference pattern would have a repeating pattern that takes roughly 1 second to play out before repeating.  If your two beams were 1000Hz apart, then the same repeating pattern would take 1 millisecond.  If they were 1,000,000Hz apart, then it would take a microsecond, and so forth.  What might be confusing you is that your paper drawing is static, a snapshot in time, while the real waves are constantly changing, moving forward.

Comment: Instead if I have two equal frequencies which are disposed differently (for example second way stars when second way is at half), what happens?

Comment: That is a good question that depends on your setup.  In that case you will see interference, but what interference depends on where the lasers are.  If the lasers are somehow perfectly coincident (coming from the same place and going in the same direction), which is not always physically possible but it's a good thought experiment, you'll see that the beams constructively or destructively interfere everywhere.  The beam will be somewhere between twice-as-bright and completely dim, depending on the phase shift.

Comment: If you have two beams which are not perfectly coincident, you have a situation that's more interesting.  Consider the case of two lasers, out of phase with each other, which then go through beam spreaders which spread the beam out but don't change its phase.  You will see an interference pattern something like (https://www.wonderwhizkids.com/resources/content/imagesv4/physics/concept/interference/interference1.gif).  This pattern is caused because, if you look at each point on the picture, there's a difference in path length between the two light sources.  This means you will see

Comment: bright constructive interference in some places, where the path length difference causes the light to constructively interfere, and dark destructive interference in some places, where the path length differences cause the light to destructively cancel.  Perhaps of interest: this is actually how holograms work.

Comment: But in your image waves have got the same frequency. If we see the waves not frontally, we don't see two waves with different frequencies, but they are the same. I'd like to see a thing like this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zjz9ystabw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56205/discussion-between-cort-ammon-and-curio).

Answer (score 0):

I think the point you're missing here at the moment is that these waves are both sinusoidal waves, and their interference pattern will simply be the algebraic sum of both waves. On the second sketch you posted, it's not that the two waves only meet up at two points during any given period and cancel the whole wave out. Instead, notice that at any point along the pink wave, there is a negative "copy" of it which resides on the yellow wave. As such, when we add both contributions up, the net result is zero. This happens for every point along the wave on your second drawing, and would be called destructive interference.

Your first sketch is obviously different. Here, it's not as obvious what the resulting curve will look like, but you can figure out what the sum of the two waves will be at any given point by adding each of their $y$ values. I took a moment and graphed two waves that are similar to yours on Desmos, and then in orange you can see what happens when you add both waves together. The resulting orange wave is the interference pattern. You can check it out [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3cispduk7w).

Comment: all right, but if I try to interfere blue laser with violet laser, I don't see a visible interference, so the waves don't add like the first sketch, which represents the two lasers

Comment: When you say that you try it, do you mean you have two physical lasers and are combining them? What exactly are you doing?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Alright, well I'd imagine it might have something to do with the waves being so close together in frequency that you don't get much of an interference pattern. Looking on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visible_spectrum), it says that violet light is between 668-789 THz, and blue light is between 606-668 THz. As such, perhaps you aren't seeing a real interference pattern because they are close to each other.

Comment: Ok, but then is there an interference between radio waves and blue waves? From what you said, I only have to sum the waves and in this case their frequencies are very different

Comment: Yes, there will be an interference pattern between radio waves and blue waves. It can happen with any wave, but while the frequency is important, the _phase_ of the waves are also important. For example, your second sketch has waves of the same frequency and amplitude, but one is shifted relative to the other so that they cancel each other out when you add them. As such, their net result is zero. This is something you would also have to take into account.

Comment: And the first? How do they sum? They have different period ( and frequency of course ) and amplitude

Comment: For the first two waves, you can think of them being added in two different ways. The first way is that you can go point by point, looking where the $y$ value is for each function, and adding those two values to get a new $y$ value, and you can then build a function from that. The second way (algebraically) can be a bit more difficult at times, since the functions can indeed have different periods and amplitudes. In that case, you have to hope that you can find a nice trigonometric identity to help you combine the waves, or you're simply going to have a larger final expression.

Comment: All right. Do two waves annul only when they have the same period and they are opposite? If two waved have the same period and they almost opposite, what happens?

Comment: How can we determine if two waves are constructive or destructive waves?

Comment: How can we add point by point in the first sketch?

Comment: Sorry about that, I was unclear about the "adding point by point" comment. What I mean is that, in principle, you could just go and look at the sketch and add each point together, but you would never do that in reality. If you look at your first sketch at the point that is three blocks away from the origin ($x=3$), you know that the yellow wave has a height of about $2$ and the pink wave is at a height of about $8$. As such, their sum would be $10$. That's how you would do it for every point, though we would use algebra instead since it is much faster.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56022/discussion-between-jeremy-cote-and-curio).

Comment: let's continue the discussion in chat